# Apache 404's on index.html

Tags: apache, windows-7, config

I'm inheriting a project and have to run an Apache web server (2.2.22) on my Windows 7 machine. I downloaded the 32-bit No SSL MSI and ran the installer, using the default/typical/recommended settings.

The only thing I changed was I overwrote my conf/httpd.conf file with one sent to me from a developer (whom I am inheriting the project from). The only changes I made to his version of httpd.conf were to the `ServerAdmin` and `ServerName` settings (I changed them to my email and my machine's name).

When I start the server and go to `localhost` in a browser I get a 403 (Forbidden) error. If I then attempt to go directly to `localhost/index.html` (and *yes*, I confirmed that I do have index.html inside my htdocs folder) I get a 404 error.

Anybody have *any* idea as to where I could start troubleshooting?!? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your DocumentRoot OK for your virtalhost ?

Comment: Yeah I just checked and the DocumentRoot points to the parent directory containing `htdocs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the problem: the DocumentRoot has to be the path of htdocs, not the parent of it.

For example, if index.html is in c:\apache\htdocs, the DocumentRoot has to be c:\apache\htdocs, not c:\apache.